# Run facebook login in localhost

Tags: facebook

I have website where i need to login from Facebook account.
when I login from facebook,  get an error as,

Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

From some other sites information,
I have downloaded and installed pagekite

but still the error shows the same.

can anyone tell me how to rectify this.
how to run and able to login to facebook.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15):

This one worked for me -

1.) In the developer.facebook.com, click on App.

2) Under settings in the "APP Domain" add localhost.

3) Click on "Add Platform" and choose "Website".

4) In the input box for site url  add 
`http://localhost:portNumber/`
  (whatever port number is applicable example 
`http://localhost:9000/`
 for play framework)

5.) Save the changes, the Fb login should work on your localhost now.

Comment: it will just redirect url as localhost/actionname
facebook is not redirecting to particular port no.

Answer (score 2):

add this url in `http://localhost` in App Domains and `http://localhost` in siteurl in facebook app configuration

Comment: sorry i couldnt get what you mean. can you make it bit clearer.

Comment: if you want run facebook login on local host then configuration your facebook app using this urls

Comment: ok. App domain and site url need to be entered as local host. Is that right?

Comment: I have entered this in facebook developer page. Is this the right way what i have done. sorry if it is a basic question, iam just struck over here.

Comment: @VijaySingh the `localhost` wont work with PHP-SDK (remember that), @user3040345 if you're using JS-SDK you're good to go, otherwise your redirect URL will go an **endless loop**

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to get it working:

1. Under **App Domain**, add `localhost`.
2. For **Add Platform** choose Website and add `localhost:port`
3. Create a test app and change your `APP_ID` in the local application.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add App Domains

> localhost

2. Site URL

> http://localhost/