# Facebook login integration to website on localhost

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

My index.php file include this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '<?php echo $appId; ?>',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        channelUrl: '<?php echo $return_url; ?>channel.php',
        oauth: true
    });
};
(function () {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

function CallAfterLogin() {
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.status === "connected") {
            LodingAnimate(); //Animate login
            FB.api('/me', function (data) {

                if (data.email == null) {
                    //Facbeook user email is empty, you can check something like this.
                    alert("You must allow us to access your email id!");
                    ResetAnimate();

                } else {
                    AjaxResponse();
                }

            });
        }
    }, {
        scope: '<?php echo $fbPermissions; ?>'
    });
}

//functions
function AjaxResponse() {
    //Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element using jQuery Load().
    $("#results").load("process_facebook.php");
}

//Show loading Image
function LodingAnimate() {
    $("#LoginButton").hide(); //hide login button once user authorize the application
    $("#results").html('<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" /> Please Wait Connecting...');
}

//Reset User button
function ResetAnimate() {
    $("#LoginButton").show(); //Show login button 
    $("#results").html(''); //reset element html
}
</script>

process_facebook.php include


      if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])&&strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest' )
    {       

    //initialize facebook sdk
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' = > $appId,
    'secret' = > $appSecret, ));

$fbuser = $facebook - > getUser();

if ($fbuser) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $me = $facebook - > api('/me'); //user
        $uid = $facebook - > getUser();
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        //echo error_log($e);
        $fbuser = null;
    }
}

// redirect user to facebook login page if empty data or fresh login requires
if (!$fbuser) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook - > getLoginUrl(array('redirect_uri' = > $return_url, false));
    header('Location: '.$loginUrl);
}

//user details
$fullname = $me['first_name'].' '.$me['last_name'];
$email = $me['email'];
/* connect to mysql using mysqli */
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);
if ($mysqli - > connect_error) {
    die('Error : ('.$mysqli - > connect_errno.') '.$mysqli - > connect_error);
}
//Check user id in our database 
$UserCount = $mysqli - > query("SELECT COUNT(id) as usercount FROM usertable WHERE fbid=$uid") - > fetch_object() - > usercount;
```

After this it will just check from database and insert and update. Still all step by step is followed in this blog:http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/05/ajax-facebook-connect-with-jquery-php

I am facing a problem. When I am login from facebook it just keep on loading no further thing happen i.e. user data are not able to display. so please provide me solution so that i can display and store facebook user data.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have grasp on your whole problem, but I remember having problems with running FB apps on local host. The problem was caused by the fact that when you register your FB app on the FB Dev site, you need to provide a domain. I solved my problem by adding a fake domain (www.localhost.com) to hosts file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and then entering it in the app settings. Of course, this requires you to use this fake domain when running your app locally. I Hope this helps.

Comment: @MarcinHabuszewski There's no problem is setting up the app on localhost. In the App Settings, you just write `http://localhost/MyTest/` and this works absolutely fine!

Comment: @sahilMittal Where should i write that.. i mean http://localhost/MyTest in domain or in site_url in facebook app setting?

Comment: @adam Azad Sir actually it just keep on loading it is not showing any user data.. i had share a blog link.. i just followed each and every step still i am not able to get user data

Comment: @SahilMittal then I guess this was fixed. A few months ago, this was the only way to make my app work with FB when running it on localhost (I haven't touched any FB apps since then).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the App Settings in the App Dashboard, you can write the **Site URL** as-

```
http://localhost/HarshTest/
```

Then in you app (i.e. `/HarshTest/index.php`), you can try the facebook login and it will work.

---

[image]

Comment: and what should I write in app domain??

Comment: You can leave that empty!

Comment: Thanks i had done as u suggested.. but still not working still keeps on loading.. my congif.php file include    $appId = 'xxxxxxxxx'; //Facebook App ID
$appSecret = 'xxxxxxxx'; // Facebook App Secret
$return_url = 'http://localhost/facebook/';  //path to script folder
$fbPermissions = 'publish_actions,email';    I had just given the path of my folder.. and other things are done as u suggested.. still not able to get that user data from facebook

Comment: You should do it step-wise, its difficult for me to debug for you. Do it step-wise, integrating facebook api is one of the simplest things to do. So, dont just copy-paste the whole bunch of code and run it; understand and post the exact portion which is causing the problem

Comment: Yaa i just followed the steps from that blog.. I tried to get that facebook api but i seriously not able to understand whats going wrong with that.. But still not able to get that facebook data.. U had done that thing in past then can u please provide me some link or reference in what way u had done this stuff.. please.. Thanks

Comment: I just read in one of the question here on stackoverflow.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779813/run-facebook-login-in-localhost just see this link and see the last comment by adam azad.. what he was saying is correct?? if yes then what should be done to resolve that

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: My exact problem is that it just keep on loading.. When i run this program and enter facebook user_id with password and then click on login after that according to this program it must show user data but here problem arises.. it just keeps on loading it is not showing any user data and also database is empty.