# Facebook redirection with Django and python-social-auth

Tags: django, facebook, python-social-auth

To locally test the ability to login in my `django` app with Facebook through `python-social-auth`, I have followed these steps:

- define a mapping from `127.0.0.1` to `www.florian.com` in `/etc/hosts`
- add `http://www.florian.com:8000/login/facebook` and `http://www.florian.com:8000/complete/facebook` in the field `OAuth valid URI redirect` in Facebook Login --> settings
- run `python manage.py runserver www.florian.com:8000`

However, when accessing `http://www.florian.com:8000/login/facebook`, I get the following error:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

However when I check the validity of this URL with the field available in the Facebook Login --> settings, it is OK.

Here are my Django files:

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from rest_framework import routers
from backend import views
from webapp import views as webapp_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views


router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet, 'User')
router.register(r'games', views.GameViewSet, 'Game')

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', webapp_views.home, name='home'),
    url('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
# FACEBOOK login/registration from Web 
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url('', include('social_django.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^test/', webapp_views.test),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^connect/', views.CustomObtainAuthToken.as_view()),
    url(r'^membership_create/', views.MembershipCreate.as_view()), 
# Facebook login/registration from REST API
    url(r'^auth/connect_with_fb/', views.ConvertTokenViewWithData.as_view()),
# standard Django login/registration from REST API
    url(r'^auth/connect_with_credentials/', views.TokenViewWithData.as_view()),
    url(r'^debug/', views.UserLoginAndIdView.as_view()),
    url(r'^auth/', include('rest_framework_social_oauth2.urls'),

        )

]

urlpatterns += router.urls
```

**login.html**

```
{% block content %}
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <br>
  <p><strong>-- OR --</strong></p>
  <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">Login with Facebook</a>

{% endblock %}
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework',
    'oauth2_provider',
    'social_django',
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2',
    'backend',
    'webapp',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',  # <--

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'WMC.urls'

SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webapp/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',

            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'WMC.wsgi.application'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',

    ),
}


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    # Facebook OAuth2
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookAppOAuth2',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',

    # django-rest-framework-social-oauth2
    'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',

    # Django
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

)

# Django client_secret for OAuth Toolkit for django-rest-social-auth
CLIENT_SECRET = '***********************************************************************************'


# Facebook configuration
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY = '***********'
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET = '*****************************'





# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Define SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE to get extra permissions from facebook. Email is not sent by default, to get it, you must request the email permission:
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_SCOPE = ['email']
SOCIAL_AUTH_FACEBOOK_PROFILE_EXTRA_PARAMS = {
    'fields': 'id, name, email'
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: This is an issue in your Facebook settings, under Settings -> Basic make sure you have: `www.florian.com` in the app domains AND under platforms, website (add it if you haven't), your website URL must be including the port number: `http://www.florian.com:8000`. It actually also works with `localhost` if you set this up as a test app. Not entirely sure which one needs the port number, try the other way round if this one doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20779813/run-facebook-login-in-localhost

Comment: I have `http://www.florian.com:8000/` as URL website and `www.florian.com` as app domain.

Comment: Go check what value the redirect_uri parameter contains in the actual login dialog URL. That exact value needs to be in your settings.

Comment: Here is what I get: `https://www.facebook.com/v2.9/dialog/oauth?client_id=143351872970742&scope=email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.florian.com%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F%3Fredirect_state%3D7GQEiddzm1KtQhzDucd8NBRmXqFPdiyc&state=7GQEiddzm1KtQhzDucd8NBRmXqFPdiyc&return_scopes=true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `1.6.0` version of the `social_core` library (part of `python-social-auth`), the field `REDIRECT_STATE` of `FacebookOAuth2` backend has been set to `False`.

As I was using the `1.5.0` version (where `REDIRECT_STATE=True`), and as the `redirect_state` changes each time in the call to the Facebook login, my app was not able to handle such a dynamic behavior.

Thus, upgrading `social_core` to version `1.7.0` solves the issue.

Comment: I am using social-auth-core==1.7.0 but still its sending state with my url. So frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [`.florian.com`]
```

to `settings.py`

Comment: `www.florian.com` is already in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`otherwise I would not have been able to access the website no?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you are using Linux development environment with Nginx installed.

I don't suggest you using 'real' urls for testing locally. You should try  something like `florian.local`.

In your `/etc/hosts` add a line like this:

`127.0.0.1    florian.local`

Add `florian.local` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in `settings.py` file.

In your `/etc/nginx/sites-available` create a file `florian` (touch florian) with content in it something like this:

```
upstream florian {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name florian.local;
    keepalive_timeout    360;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://florian;
        proxy_connect_timeout       600;
        proxy_send_timeout          600;
        proxy_read_timeout          600;
        send_timeout                600;
    }


}
```

CD into `sites-enabled` and create soft link for the previously created file:

`ln -s ../sites-available/florian .`

At the end, don't forget to restart nginx, like:

`sudo service nginx restart`

Run your local development server:

`./manage.py runserver 8000`,

you can then access it via `http://127.0.0.1:8000` or via `http://florian.local`.

I've used this method successfully to authenticate to my local app with Facebook, Twitter and Google account.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is already answered, but your site should be using https instead of http.

Example:

Instead of http://www.florian.com:8000/complete/facebook
Used this one: https://www.florian.com:8000/complete/facebook

Facebook is not accepting http site.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This looks like a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For childrens:

add https://yourdomain.example/oauth/complete/facebook/ to "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" on facebook developers website in "Client OAuth Settings" tab.

/oauth/ - it's name of your django social url.